# How to do a DFS on a tree? (not necessarily binary)

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

I have a tree of `n` nodes (labeled `0 to n`). I used two vectors to hold the edge information.

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<int>> graph;
```

The input is `n-1` edges in the form:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
and so on
```

I'm told node `0` is always the root node.
I scan the edges using the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    g[a].push_back(b);
    g[b].push_back(a); // the second approach doesn't use this line
}
```

This is my simple dfs:

```
void dfs(graph &g, int v) {
    std::vector<int> visited; // I don't use a visited array for the second approach
    for (int i = 0; i < g.size(); i++) {
        visited.push_back(0);
    }
    std::stack<int> s;
    std::set<int> t;
    s.push(v);
    while (!s.empty()) {
        int i = s.top(); s.pop();
        // do stuff
        for (int i = 0; i < g[v].size(); i++) {
            if (!visited[i]) {
                visited[i] = true;
                s.push(g[v][i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For example say we have 4 nodes and the following edges:

```
0 1
0 2
3 2
2 4
```

Say that I'm interested in the sub tree starting at `2`. The above approach won't work because I'm inserting undirected edges `0 2` and `2 0`. So when I start my `dfs` at `2` I add node `0` to my stack which is wrong.

I tried another approach of only inserting the edges given only but that also didn't work because in the example I would've inserted `3 2` which is an edge from `3` to node `2` and so when I start my `dfs` at node `2` I won't be able to reach node `3`.

I feel like the problem is simple and I'm missing some big idea!

Answer (score 1):

Since your graph is a rooted tree, you can do the following preprocessing.

1. Start a DFS from root (vertex #0);
2. For each vertex **u**, store its *parent* **v**. It means that if you travel alongside shortest path from root to **u**, the second-to-last vertex on this path will be **v**. Notice that in any tree there is exactly one shortest path from one vertex to another. Let's say that you have an array `parent` such that `parent[u] = v` according to above definition, and `parent[0] = -1`.
   You can compute `parent` array by noticing, that if you do `s.push(g[v][i])`, then `v` is the parent of `i` (otherwise you would have visited `i` first);
3. Since `parent[v]` is the previous vertex on shortest path from global root (vertex 0), it is also the previous vertex on shortest path from any vertex **x**, which contains **v** in its subtree.

Now when you want to DFS over subtree of vertex **u**, you do DFS as you do it now, but *do not visit the parent* of any vertex. Say, if you want to do `s.push(v)`, while `parent[u] = v`, do not do it. This way you will never leave the subtree of **u**.

Actually, knowing `parent`, you can get rid of your `visited` array. When you "do stuff" with vertex **v**, the only neighbour of **v** that is already visited is `parent[v]`. This property does not depend on the initial vertex, whose subtree you want to traverse. The DFS code would look like this (assuming you've done preprocessing to obtain `parent`:

```
  void dfs(graph &g, vector<int> &parent, int v) {
    std::stack<int> s;
    s.push(v);
    while (!s.empty()) {
        int v = s.top(); s.pop(); // By the way, you have mistake here: int i = s.top().
        // do stuff
        for (int i = 0; i < g[v].size(); i++) {
            if (parent[v] != g[v][i]) {
                s.push(g[v][i]);
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

PS This approach is somehow similar to your second approach: it only treats edges that go from root to subtree. But it does not have the flaw, such as in your example with "3 2" being the wrong direction, because you infer direction algorithmically by doing DFS from root.